# react-pose: my dynamic props doesn't trigger change on my animated element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I'm trying to make that when you click on a div the opacity decrease. 
But despite the fact that the dynamic value associated with my posed element decrease, the opacity of the box remain the same.

It seems to me that I have followed [the rules of the doc](https://popmotion.io/pose/learn/dynamic-props/)

[here my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ojqxpmj4rq)

Here my react snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import posed from "react-pose";
import './styles.css';

const Box = posed.div({
  visible: {
   // opacity: ({ opacityValue }) => ({ opacity: opacityValue }), doesn't work
    // opacity:  ({opacityValue}) ,
    opacity: ({ opacityValue }) => opacityValue,
    transition: { duration: 1000 }
  }
})
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isVisible: true,
    opacityValue: 1
  };

  handleHover = () => { 
    console.log("opacity value: ", this.state.opacityValue)
    console.log("decrease opacity value")
    this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => {
      return {
        opacityValue: previousState.opacityValue - 0.1
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { isVisible } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        trigger animation from a div to an another one
      <Box
          onPoseComplete={console.log("pose complete :)")}
          className="box"
          opacityValue={this.state.opacityValue}
         pose= "visible" 
        />

        <div
          onClick={() => this.handleHover()}
          // onMouseLeave={this.handleHover}
          className="box_to_hover"
        >
          click on me to decrease box opacity
      </div>
      </div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

How make the opacity follow the value of the props?
Any hint would be great, 
thanks

Comment: I think this is how react-pose was meant to be used: https://codesandbox.io/s/61w3wjy97w because mostly, whatever I do, only the stuff I pass in 'pose' will trigger a re-render. Please wait for someone with more react-pose experience to answer, though.

Comment: In the meantime, here's a simple way of doing the exact same thing with styled-components: https://codesandbox.io/s/729zykpom0